# zlib.output_compression Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, mamp

В Вордпрессе всплывает такое предупреждение:
Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1)
Появилось оно после импорта всяких тестовых записей с https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test (Делаю тему, и хотел закинуть кучу записей, чтобы проверить как оно смотрится)
Основоное решение, которое все предлагают в этом случае - поставить zlib.output_compression = Off в настройках php...
Но ведь это определенно костыль, а не решение проблемы. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить нормально.
Проверяю на локальном сервере через MAMP с LEMP.

Comment: MAMP с LEMP - это мощно.

Comment: Напишите, где это замечание возникает и при каких условиях, иначе это не вопрос,а предложение гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: на всех страницах и постах, включая админку, то есть везде

Comment: а что посоветуете для локальной разработки?

Comment: К вашему сведению, ob_end_flush() в ядре WordPress встречается всего 1 раз, и в таком контексте, который на 99.9% не связан с обычной работой. Почитайте, как задать хороший вопрос по WP: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-wordpress?s=1|37.4493

Comment: MAMP - это среда для Windows и Mac. Включает в себя Apache, mySQL. php. LEMP - совсем другой программный стек: Linux + nginx + mysql + php. MAMP и LEMP даже теоретически не могут быть одновременно на одной машине.

Comment: я имел ввиду мамп на nginx)) тупанул, сорри))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72625/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-paul-wall).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставлю ответ, чтобы если кто будет читать, знал в чем было дело. 
WordPress оказывается не совместим с zlib.output_compression

Первая мысль, которая пришла в голову, что если я отключу компрессию, то ее ж просто не будет, а это получается - костыль. Но по факту через тот же nginx идет своя gzip компрессия (если вы ее конечно там настроили). И, получается, отключить в php.ini параметр zlib.output_compression = Off является самым правильным решением этой проблемы.